# Ruby on Rails coffeescript after a call ajax call

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I have a screen which eventually the user will click a button which activate a dialog scren which calls ajax.

The problem I have is that the art.js.coffee has the following code

```
$(".singleevent").click ->
  $("#decide").val $(this).attr("dataid")
```

But this doesn't apply to the code once I load the ajax page, which could be 10 minutes later or so, is there a way for me to add a addlistener to an element which doesn't exist at the moment or to reload the coffeescript only.

Thank you, the ajax, in the dialog is a load screen but only load the div in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `on()`: http://api.jquery.com/on/

This will allow you to define events on elements which don't yet exist on the page.

Comment: I implemented the following   $(".singleevent").on "click", (event) ->
    $("#decide").val $(this).attr("dataid") but it doesn't do anything

Comment: It's not quite that straightforward - read the docs I linked to, in particular the section about "picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached".